# Will there be any consequence to exceeding age 24 for Upanayana?

Tags: upanayanam

Apastamba Gryha Sutra, in verse 1.1.1.27, places a maximum age limit of 24 for the Upanayana ceremony.

If anyone exceeds this age for the ceremony, will there be any negative consequence?

Comment: will there be any consequence of going past deadline for a job application ? will there be any consequence of not paying bill by end of month ? will there be any consequence of going to job at 1pm instead of 9am ? will there be any negative consequence ? you won't get the desired benefit, simple as that.

Comment: Better late then never.

Comment: I heard that if someone passed the prescribed age, he should do Vratyasoma Yajna before he can undergo Upanayana.